# Python Django in how to daily data to weekly conversation in error in ValueError at /filter 'DATE' is not in list

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have daily data that data convert in weekly data. That in problem in error is ValueError at /filter

'DATE' is not in list

view.py

```
def filter(request):
   date_min = request.POST.get('date_min')
   date_max = request.POST.get('date_max')

   qs = weather_data.pdobjects.filter(DATE__range=(date_min,date_max))
   df = pd.DataFrame(qs)
   logic = {'ET':'sum','EP':'sum','BSS':'sum','RF':'sum','WS':'sum','DT1':'sum','WT1':'sum','DT2':'sum','WT2':'sum','MAXT':'sum','MINT':'sum','RH11':'sum','RH22':'sum','VP11':'sum','VP11':'sum','CLOUDM':'sum','CLOUDE':'sum','SOIL1':'sum','SOIL2':'sum','SOIL3':'sum','SOIL4':'sum','SOIL5':'sum','SOIL6':'sum','MinTtest':'sum','MaxTtest1':'sum','MaxTtest2':'sum'}
   offset = pd.offsets.timedelta(days=-6)
   df = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=['DATE'], index_col=['DATE'])
   df = df.resample('W', loffset=offset).apply(logic)
   df.head()

   return render(request,"reports.html",locals())
```

ValueError at /filter

'DATE' is not in list

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/filter
Django Version:     2.2.3
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:

'DATE' is not in list

Exception Location:     C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _set, line 2290
Python Executable:  C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:

['E:\sem-7_Rupesh\Project\prectis',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages',
 'c:\users\student\src\django-import-export',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\odf',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\odf',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\odf',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\odf',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\odf',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\odf',
 'C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\odf']

Server time:    Wed, 11 Sep 2019 17:52:53 +0000